# Consulta sobre códigos en Python

Tags: python

Quisiera saber de que forma puedo pasar información obtenida por un código a otro código en Python. Osea, he escrito un código de adquisición de datos, y otro para visualización de estos que corren en diferentes momentos de forma individual, sin embargo, quiero que el de visualización obtenga, cuando se active, los valores calculados en el código de adquisición.

Este es el código con funcionas para adquirir los datos, los cuales simulo con la función random porque aun no poseo los sensores.

```
#Funciones
def bpm():                #Esta funcion se usa para la medicion del BPM. 
    randbpm=random.randint(60,90)
    lcd.clear()
    lcd.message(' Pulsos por minuto' +
                '\n\n         ' + str(randbpm))
    time.sleep(0.5)

def temp():               #Esta funcion define la temperatura del cuerpo.
    randtemp=random.randint(30,38)
    lcd.clear()
    lcd.message('Temperatura corporal' +
                '\n\n         ' + str(randtemp))  
    time.sleep(0.5) 

def oxig():               #Esta funcion define el oxigeno en la sangre.
    randoxi=random.randint(20,80)
    lcd.clear()
    lcd.message('Oxigeno en la sangre' +
                '\n\n         ' + str(randoxi))   
    time.sleep(0.5) 

def seleccion(a):
    if a < 0:  
        a=2
        lcd.clear()
        lcd.message("Seleccione:\n\n        <O2>")
        selec=2                   
    elif a == 0:                      
        lcd.clear()
        lcd.message("Seleccione:\n\n       <BPM>")
        selec=0              
    elif a == 1:                         
        lcd.clear()
        lcd.message("Seleccione:\n\n       <TEMP>")
        selec=1                      
    elif a == 2:                            
        lcd.clear()
        lcd.message("Seleccione:\n\n        <O2>")
        selec=2                  
    elif a > 2:                        
        a=0
        lcd.clear()
        lcd.message("Seleccione:\n\n       <BPM>")
        selec=0
    return [selec, a]
```

Y este es el codigo que visualiza dichos datos en el LCD.

```
while True:
    
    while apagar==0:
        seleccion(a)
        time.sleep(1.0)
        
        while True:            
            if GPIO.input(19) == GPIO.HIGH:                   
                a-=1
                time.sleep(0.2)
                seleccion(a)                
                [selec, a]=seleccion(a) 
                        
            if GPIO.input(13) == GPIO.HIGH:                    
                a+=1
                time.sleep(0.2)                
                seleccion(a)                
                [selec, a]=seleccion(a)     
                
            if GPIO.input(26) == GPIO.HIGH:               
                menu=0
                break
            
            if GPIO.input(6) == GPIO.HIGH:                
                lcd.clear()
                apagar+=1
                lcd.message('\n      Sistema\n      Apagado')
                time.sleep(1.5)
                lcd.clear()
                break
            
        while menu==0:                   
            if selec == 0:                  
                lcd.clear()
                lcd.message('\n    Medicion de \n       BPM...')
                time.sleep(1.0)  
                
                while GPIO.input(26)==GPIO.LOW:
                    
                    menu=1
                    bpm()
                        
            if selec == 1:                    
                lcd.clear()
                lcd.message('\n    Medicion de \n   Temperatura...')
                time.sleep(1.0)      
                
                while GPIO.input(26)==GPIO.LOW:
                    
                    menu=1
                    temp()     
                                
            if selec == 2:                   
                lcd.clear()
                lcd.message('\n    Medicion de \n   Oxigeno...')
                time.sleep(1.0)
                        
                while GPIO.input(26)==GPIO.LOW:
                    
                    menu=1
                    oxig()                                                                                               
    
    if GPIO.input(6)== GPIO.HIGH:        
        lcd.message('\n      Sistema\n     Encendido')
        apagar-=1
        time.sleep(2.5)
```

Ambos códigos los tengo en una misma hoja de texto, los suelo correr juntos, pero quiero dividirlos en dos hojas de texto porque deseo que el primero este ejecutado en todo momento y el segundo solo cuando se requiera y no conozco forma de hacerlo en la misma hoja de programación ya que recién estoy aprendiendo a programar.

Comment: Para que podamos ayudarte te sugiero que coloques tu codigo o al menos el fragmento con el que tienes problemas, te recomiendo que revises el [tour] y también [ask] para saber como pregúntar.

Comment: Que has intentado? Que te impide lograrlo? Has hecho algo por lo menos? Y si adjuntas el código en cuestión?

Comment: Ya aumente mas información a mi pregunta, espero así sea mas comprensible, disculpen la molestia.

Comment: Hoja de texto se referira a archivos? en el caso que sean dos programas distintos, entonces vas a necesitar pasar la informacion de uno a otro de alguna manera, en la forma de datos, guardandolos en un archivo, base de datos o donde te convenga.

Comment: Exactamente, eso es lo que estoy consultando, ahora que leo tu respuesta, podría guardar la información de los sensores en un documento y hacer que el otro programa lo lea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres pasar datos de un programa a otro, tienes que usar algún intermediario. La manera más fácil que se me ocurre es con un archivo de texto.

Hay que escribir una variable obtenida del primer programa en un archivo de texto, luego en el segundo programa almacenar la lectura de dicho archivo de texto y procesarlo como se desee.

A continuación te dejo un ejemplo para que te quede más claro.

**Primer programa:**

```
a = "Estoy en el primer programa"

with open("archivo.txt","w+") as archivo:
    archivo.write(eval(f"a"))
    archivo.close()
```

En este programa almacenamos información en la variable `a`(para este ejemplo uso una cadena, pero perfectamente puede ser el valor retorna por una función o algo más complejo). Luego la variable se escribe en un archivo.

**Segundo programa:**

```
with open("archivo.txt","r+") as archivo:
    b = archivo.read()

print(b)
```

En el segundo programa se almacena la lectura del archivo en cuestión en un variable, finalmente se procesa esa variable.

**El resultado:**

```
Estoy en el primer programa
```

Se obtiene este resultado ya que la manera en que procesé es dato fue con un simple `print()`

**Nota:** Es muy importante definir la forma de acceso al archivo indicada, si leemos el archivo con `w+` se va a borrar todo, la lectura se debe de hacer con `r+`.

Espero que te haya servido, saludos.

Comment: Gracias compañero, así me queda bastante claro y como al información con la que trabajaré  se puede tomar como texto, me servirá mucho tu ejemplo. Agradezco tu tiempo y tu buena explicación.